# Model hook throwing error. Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my application users have many meals. meals belong to a user. I have it so that a user can currently post a meal by creating a record and saving it. Immediately after completing this my console threw the error:

`Error: Assertion Failed: You need to pass a model name to the store's modelFor method at new Error (native)`

I then wrote my model hook for getting meals, when I started to get the error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of undefined`

I am not certain what is causing this. Here is my code:

User Model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  height: DS.attr('number'),
  weight: DS.attr('number'),
  age: DS.attr('number'),
  tdee: DS.attr('number'),
  gender: DS.attr('string'),
  activity_level: DS.attr('number'),
  meals: hasMany('meal')
});
```

Meal model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { belongsTo, hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  meal_type: DS.attr('string'),
  created_at: DS.attr('date'),
  user: belongsTo('user'),
  // meal_items: hasMany('meal_item')
});
```

Meal route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('meal');
  },
  actions: {
    createMeal(data) {
      let meal = this.get('store').createRecord('meal', data);
      meal.save();
    }
  }
});
```

I am new to ember, but have a hunch it may be related to explicit inverses? An advice is appreciated. I can post more code if something needs clarification.

EDIT:

The GET request to the server successful. The meal data is in the DS.

So I pass the createMeal action down to my create-meal component:

`{{create-meal meals=model createMeal="createMeal"}}`

The component sends this action back up on submit:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  form: {},
  actions: {
    submit (){
      this.sendAction('createMeal', this.get('form'));
    }
  }
});
```

Here is my template for that component:

```
<label class="col-md-3">Create A Meal</label>
<div class="input-group col-md-8 col-centered create-meal-div">
  {{input value=form.meal_type type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Meal Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"}}
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary" {{action "submit" form on "submit"}}> Start Adding Food</button></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 food-search-div">
  {{food-search}}
</div>
```

EDIT 2:

rails controller meal create action:

```
  def create
    # binding.pry
    @meal = current_user.meals.build(meal_params)

    if @meal.save
      render json: @meal, status: :created, location: @meal
    else
      render json: @meal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

SOLVED:

REMOVING the `user: belongsTo('user'),` in my meal model go rid of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here in this line - router

```
return this.get('store').findAll('meal');
```

Try this but it is weird it should work

```
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('meal');
}
```

Inside controllers you need to use this.get('store') when you are inside route just this.store. Try that and let me know if it works. Also inside your route set the action to accept the model as param, like this

```
actions: {
  update(model){
    model.save().then( ....
```

This can be triggered from template like this

```
<form {{action 'update' model on='submit'}} autocomplete="off">
```

In this way you do not need to get this.store in your route - you will have a model passed and you can just go to save

Hope it helps

EDIT: also this would prevent ember cli to precompile

user: belongsTo('user'),
  // meal_items: hasMany('meal_item')

so it should be without ,

user: belongsTo('user')
  // meal_items: hasMany('meal_item')

Comment: still getting the same error... not sure what to do. I've scoured past questions.

Comment: how do you pass this data createMeal(data) {...show the code that triggers the data...see my updated answer and edit the code so that inside createMeal you pass in model directly

Comment: I put my original code for my component in the edit above. I will start to edit my action how you suggested.

Comment: Before you edit the action lets try this in your route createMeal just for testing let meal = this.get('store').createRecord('meal'); meal.save() I want ot make sure that you are able to create records before I look closely to component. So try not use use params data instead pass in hard coded values after model name

Comment: I can create meals... My component successfully sends data back up and creates a record in the DS and will successfully POST to my backend on meal.save();

Comment: You use rails on server side? Right? After you create record do you return the json of that record? So it needs to do something like meal = Meal.create()...then later render json:meal status: :created...you need to return created record to ember. Please post a code of def create method for meal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114878/discussion-between-mirza-memic-and-atache).